# Identity server 4 add information to userinfo endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, wordpress, identityserver4, userinfo

I currently have an authentication system based on Identity server 4 (code in .net core), my system works and I have several applications developed in .net that are connected to it. I've been asked to make it possible to use my server to connect to a Wordpress application. I added the mini orange OAuth/OpenID Connect Single Sign On plugin to manage my connection. It works fine. My problem is with retrieving the user's login information. In mini orange's connection test interface, the only value displayed is "sub". I searched, but couldn't find a way to make the other user information (email, first name, last name) appear.

Program.cs of my identity server

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = optionsBuilder =>
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("BddConnectContext"),
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
    })
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUtilisateurRepository, UtilisateurRepository>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BddContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("BddContext")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseIdentityServer();

app.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(option =>
{
    option.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});

app.Run();
```

My WordPress client
[image]

I'm not sure if this information is enough, but if it's missing I could add it without any problem.

**EDIT**

Below is the general configuration of my client

```
{
    "AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime": 2592000,
    "AccessTokenLifetime": 3600,
    "AccessTokenType": 0,
    "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": false,
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true,
    "AllowPlainTextPkce": false,
    "AllowRememberConsent": true,
    "AllowedCorsOrigins": [],
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [
        "implicit"
    ],
    "AllowedIdentityTokenSigningAlgorithms": [],
    "AllowedScopes": [
        "email",
        "openid",
        "profile"
    ],
    "AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken": true,
    "AlwaysSendClientClaims": false,
    "AuthorizationCodeLifetime": 300,
    "BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired": true,
    "BackChannelLogoutUri": null,
    "CibaLifetime": null,
    "Claims": [],
    "ClientClaimsPrefix": "client_",
    "ClientId": "wordpress",
    "ClientName": "My WordPress",
    "ClientSecrets": [],
    "ClientUri": null,
    "ConsentLifetime": null,
    "CoordinateLifetimeWithUserSession": false,
    "Description": null,
    "DeviceCodeLifetime": 300,
    "EnableLocalLogin": true,
    "Enabled": true,
    "FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired": true,
    "FrontChannelLogoutUri": null,
    "IdentityProviderRestrictions": [],
    "IdentityTokenLifetime": 300,
    "IncludeJwtId": false,
    "LogoUri": null,
    "PairWiseSubjectSalt": null,
    "PollingInterval": 0,
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
        "https://sandbox.miniorange.com/signout-callback-oidc"
    ],
    "Properties": {},
    "ProtocolType": "oidc",
    "RedirectUris": [
        "https://sandbox.miniorange.com/314cfc5"
    ],
    "RefreshTokenExpiration": 1,
    "RefreshTokenUsage": 1,
    "RequireClientSecret": true,
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "RequirePkce": false,
    "RequireRequestObject": false,
    "SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime": 1296000,
    "UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh": false,
    "UserCodeType": null,
    "UserSsoLifetime": null
}
```

I also put the configuration of my identity server if it helps

```
{
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://my-server.com/connect/authorize",
    "authorization_response_iss_parameter_supported": true,
    "backchannel_authentication_endpoint": "https://my-server.com/connect/ciba",
    "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "backchannel_token_delivery_modes_supported": [
        "poll"
    ],
    "backchannel_user_code_parameter_supported": true,
    "check_session_iframe": "https://my-server.com/connect/checksession",
    "claims_supported": [
        "sub",
        "name",
        "email",
        "birthdate",
        "family_name",
        "gender",
        "given_name",
        "locale",
        "middle_name",
        "nickname",
        "picture",
        "preferred_username",
        "profile",
        "updated_at",
        "website",
        "zoneinfo"
    ],
    "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
        "plain",
        "S256"
    ],
    "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://my-server.com/connect/deviceauthorization",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://my-server.com/connect/endsession",
    "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
    "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
    "grant_types_supported": [
        "authorization_code",
        "client_credentials",
        "refresh_token",
        "implicit",
        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code",
        "urn:openid:params:grant-type:ciba"
    ],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "RS256"
    ],
    "introspection_endpoint": "https://my-server.com/connect/introspect",
    "issuer": "https://my-server.com",
    "jwks_uri": "https://my-server.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
    "request_object_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "RS256",
        "RS384",
        "RS512",
        "PS256",
        "PS384",
        "PS512",
        "ES256",
        "ES384",
        "ES512",
        "HS256",
        "HS384",
        "HS512"
    ],
    "request_parameter_supported": true,
    "response_modes_supported": [
        "form_post",
        "query",
        "fragment"
    ],
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code",
        "token",
        "id_token",
        "id_token token",
        "code id_token",
        "code token",
        "code id_token token"
    ],
    "revocation_endpoint": "https://my-server.com/connect/revocation",
    "scopes_supported": [
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "email",
        "offline_access"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "public"
    ],
    "token_endpoint": "https://my-server.com/connect/token",
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_basic",
        "client_secret_post"
    ],
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://my-server.com/connect/userinfo"
}
```

My ProfileService

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IUserCustomRepository _userRepository;

    public ProfileService(IUserCustomRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var idUserCustom = context.Subject.FindFirst(x => x.Type == "IdUserCustom");
        if (idUserCustom != null)
        {
            var utilisateur = _userRepository.GetUserCustomById(int.Parse(idUserCustom.Value));
            if (utilisateur != null)
            {
                var listAppli = _userRepository.ListApplicationUser(utilisateur).OrderBy(x => x.RangAffichage).ToList();
                context.IssuedClaims = GetClaims(utilisateur, listAppli);
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private List<Claim> GetClaims(UserCustom customUser, List<Application> listAppli)
    {
        var result = new List<Claim>
        {
            new(JwtClaimTypes.Name, customUser.PrenomUserCustom ?? ""),
            new(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, customUser.NomUserCustom ?? ""),
            new(JwtClaimTypes.Email, customUser.EmailUserCustom ?? ""),
            new("Login", customUser.LoginUserCustom),
            new("UserCustom", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customUser))
        };

        if (listAppli.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var appli in listAppli)
            {
                var item = new Claim("Application", appli.LibelleApplication);
                result.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Does the IdentityServer actually provide user claims as part of the profile scope that you ask for? try ask for the scopes "openid email profile". see https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I went to look at your link, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to validate that my server provides all the user's scopes.
In my database I've added the 3 scopes "openid, email and profile" to the client as well as in the client-side call, but I still only have "sub" coming up in the response.

Comment: Have you mapped the actual claims in identityServer to the profile? (does the claims in the database match the ones listed in the profile?)

Comment: You should explore this blog https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/ and also verify what the ID-token and optional request to the userinfo endpoint looks like.

Comment: Also, in IdentityServer, you can try to enable this client setting "AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken". https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/reference/models/client/

Comment: Let me know if it works, I and I can compose a real answer here.

Comment: I've consulted the various links and performed the various manipulations but nothing seems to change. I'm going to add some more elements to my question

Comment: you need to look inside the ID-token and also what is available from the UserInfo endpoint. the claims will be available in either location, do verify that. Perhaps post to the question a sample ID token and what is returned from the userinfo endpoint

Comment: I think you should show your `ProfileService` implementation (`.AddProfileService<ProfileService>();`)

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos  I've just added the initialization of my ProfileService to the initial post

Comment: IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
try this